# First order Linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve :

$$
     y'=\tan(x)\cdot y + \frac{1}{\cos(x)}\cdot\frac{2x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}
   $$

So let $$\gamma=e^{-\int_{}\tan(x)dx}$$ .
For $${-\int_{}\tan(x)dx}$$ I got as a result $$-\ln(\cos(x))+C$$ ,so
 $$\gamma=e^{-\ln(\cos(x))+C}=\frac{1}{\cos(x)} +e^C$$ and $$\gamma'=\frac{\tan(x)}{\cos(x)}$$
Then using the substitution $y=u\gamma$ for some u ,the equation becomes:
$v'\gamma+v\gamma'-\tan(x)vy=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}\cdot\frac{2x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$  or . It is supposed the $v$'s to get destroyed and only $v'$ to be left, but they are not.Where am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Integrating factor is cos x

Comment: You mean the result from finding the integral of -tan(x) is ln(cos(x)) not ln(cos(x)) +C?

Comment: You have written IF=1/cos x

Comment: Yes , constant is also not required. The formula is just for calculating the IF. It involves an integral but the constant has not to be included.

Comment: So making the result of the integral ln(cos(x)) is correct in my problem?

Comment: $\gamma=e^{-\int tan x dx}=e^{ln(cos(x))}=cos(x)$.

Comment: So, for the solution:$y cos x =\int \frac{2x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} dx$

Comment: Thanks !!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I get for the equation $$ v'cos(x)-vsin(x) -tg(x)vcos(x)= ... $$ ,the v's should cancel but they don't? @Tojrah

Comment: It is $$y(x)=\frac{2\sqrt{x^2+1}}{\cos(x)}+\frac{C}{\cos(x)}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computing $$\mu=e^{\int\tan(x)dx}=\cos(x)$$ and we get
$$\cos(x)y'(x)+\frac{d\cos(x)}{dx}y(x)=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
this can be written as
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\cos(x)y(x)\right)=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$